# If condition in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

is that possible to implement an if condition via XAML for wpf , if yes please provide the skeleton for if condition for checking .net framework version in xaml.

I am sharing xaml for Visual studio 2010 and 2008 , i wanna execute specific code snippet for vs2010 and hide the same for vs2008

Comment: I am sharing xaml for Visual studio 2010 and 2008 , i wanna execute specific code snippet for vs2010 and hide the same for vs2008 ..

Comment: Why do you want to do it in XAML only ?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Maybe you should look at triggers they provide way to do conditional processing in XAML, look at converters

Answer (score 9):

Yes, they're called `Trigger`s. There are different kinds and they react to changes in values of data that is data bound, events that are fired, or even the state of user interface controls. You can find a good article describing them in the [Triggers in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF) post on Code Project.

EDIT >>>

I have just added your comment into your question and I have to say that putting such an important part of your question into a comment was not a good idea... as such, most of the answers so far do not answer your *actual* question. For this reason, I have downvoted your question.

In response to your *actual* question, no, I do not believe that you can use conditional XAML which can identify the difference between versions of Visual Studio. If you told us what you end goal is, then we *may* still be able to help.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at using a Converter in your XAML. With a Converter, you can make decisions in your XAML by executing code. For example, this will make my button visible under certain conditions:

XAML

```XAML
<Button
    x:Name="btnMyButton"
    Margin="2,0"
    Command="{Binding Model.MyButtonCommand}"
    Content="My Text"
    Visibility="{Binding Model.IsShowMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=False}"
/>
```

C# Class

```C#
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
    // Do the conversion 
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
      // UnDo conversion
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember to add the reference to the converter in the Window.Resources element of your xaml. 

    `<Window.Resources> 
    <local: BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can have a look at this http://josheinstein.com/blog/2010/06/switchconverter-a-switch-statement-for-xaml/

I haven't tried it but it seems that this may suite you.

**Edit:**

Here is code of SwitchConverter as [Josh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81769/josh) site seems to be down -

```
/// <summary>
/// A converter that accepts <see cref="SwitchConverterCase"/>s and converts them to the 
/// Then property of the case.
/// </summary>
[ContentProperty("Cases")]
public class SwitchConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // Converter instances.
    List<SwitchConverterCase> _cases;

    #region Public Properties.
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets an array of <see cref="SwitchConverterCase"/>s that this converter can use to produde values from.
    /// </summary>
    public List<SwitchConverterCase> Cases { get { return _cases; } set { _cases = value; } }
    #endregion
    #region Construction.
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SwitchConverter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SwitchConverter()
    {
        // Create the cases array.
        _cases = new List<SwitchConverterCase>();
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value produced by the binding source.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The type of the binding target property.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
    /// </returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // This will be the results of the operation.
        object results = null;

        // I'm only willing to convert SwitchConverterCases in this converter and no nulls!
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        // I need to find out if the case that matches this value actually exists in this converters cases collection.
        if (_cases != null && _cases.Count > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < _cases.Count; i++)
            {
                // Get a reference to this case.
                SwitchConverterCase targetCase = _cases[i];

                // Check to see if the value is the cases When parameter.
                if (value == targetCase || value.ToString().ToUpper() == targetCase.When.ToString().ToUpper())
                {
                    // We've got what we want, the results can now be set to the Then property
                    // of the case we're on.
                    results = targetCase.Then;

                    // All done, get out of the loop.
                    break;
                }
            }

        // return the results.
        return results;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value that is produced by the binding target.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The type to convert to.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
    /// </returns>
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents a case for a switch converter.
/// </summary>
[ContentProperty("Then")]
public class SwitchConverterCase
{
    // case instances.
    string _when;
    object _then;

    #region Public Properties.
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the condition of the case.
    /// </summary>
    public string When { get { return _when; } set { _when = value; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the results of this case when run through a <see cref="SwitchConverter"/>
    /// </summary>
    public object Then { get { return _then; } set { _then = value; } }
    #endregion
    #region Construction.
    /// <summary>
    /// Switches the converter.
    /// </summary>
    public SwitchConverterCase()
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SwitchConverterCase"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="when">The condition of the case.</param>
    /// <param name="then">The results of this case when run through a <see cref="SwitchConverter"/>.</param>
    public SwitchConverterCase(string when, object then)
    {
        // Hook up the instances.
        this._then = then;
        this._when = when;
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("When={0}; Then={1}", When.ToString(), Then.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The blog seems to be down.  Can you summarize it or provide an alternate blog?