# Apply a style to a control from a button's dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, custom-controls

I have created a custom control that serves as the basis for a few others I'm making. I've then defined control templates for each one, so now I can do the following:

```xml
<!-- First layout -->
<custom:MyCustomControl Style="{StaticResource CustomStyle1}" />
<!-- Second layout -->
<custom:MyCustomControl Style="{StaticResource CustomStyle2}" />
...
etc.
```

I then wanted to make it so I could switch from one style to another with the press of a button. My initial idea to do this was to create custom `Button` with a `StyleToApply` dependency property and a way to find its containing parent. I would then set the button's `OnClick` method to change the style of its containing control's to that of the button's dependency property. However, my styles don't get recognised:

```xml
<!-- Within a custom control or user control -->
<local:StyleButton StyleToApply="{StaticResource ResourceKey}" ... />
                                                      ^ no suggested styles
```

Is it even possible to achieve this? If so, how? If not, what could I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for this would be to have both controls in your XAML and bind their `Visibility` to a property in your viewmodel i.e. bind Control1's Visibility to `public bool StandardLayout` in your viewmodel, and Control2's Visibility to the inverse of that.

Idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18314286/4364057) and enhancement by me:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
</Window.Resources>

<!-- First layout -->
<custom:MyCustomControl Style="{StaticResource CustomStyle1}" Visibility="{Binding StandardLayout, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}" />
<!-- Second layout -->
<custom:MyCustomControl Style="{StaticResource CustomStyle2}" Visibility="{Binding StandardLayout, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}, ConverterParameter=Inverted}"/>
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried the ConverterParameter=Inverted part myself yet, you might have to either make another viewmodel property that inverts the first, or an InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter like [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534575/how-do-i-invert-booleantovisibilityconverter).

Edit: Then the button, when clicked, would just flip the bool around and the controls switch visibilities.